# Making text skip to below image instead of wrapping on mobile device

Tags: css, image, screen

I have two category blog layout pages on my guitar website. The intro article images are set to "float: left" which makes the design work on devices with either really small screens or if they have larger screens/flipped screens to horizontal mode.

In vertical mode, on large phone screens, the text wraps around the image in an odd way. Here I would prefer if the text simply just skipped to below the image. You can see what I mean [here](http://www.responsinator.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fguitarguitar.net%2Fjoomla%2Findex.php%2Fbasic-guides).

The first example is the effect that I'm after, but on iPhone 6 and nexus phones the wrap effect is unwanted.

Is there any way to make this happen using CSS?

I have tried usin the min-width CSS property but it does not have any effect.

Using Joomla vs 3.6.5, protostar template.

Comment: You can use `clear` property on the text --> https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clear

Answer (score 1):

I found two solutions:

```
.pull-left.item-image {
    float: none; /* option one */
    width: 100%; /* option two */
}
```

Only `float` or only `width` (or both) will solve your problem. But, please note this will affect the image, not only in the mobile view. So you need to play around with the window's width and see what's the maximum height for the change. then, use @media on CSS (lets say you want it to apply for every screen that is thinner than 450px:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
    .pull-left.item-image { ... }
}
```